# "canvas1.getContext is not a function" error when creating a canvas element via XmlService

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, canvas

I have been working on making projects inside Google Apps Script but came across a problem.

I am currently trying to get the individual pixels of an image, by using an HTML canvas(if you know of another way to get pixel data from an image in JS, please let me know). The problem is, Google Apps Script doesn't seem to have a getContext method for the canvas. I'm not sure if this is done purposely, or if it is some kind of bug.

Code:

```
var img = XmlService.createElement('img');
img.src = query;
var canvas1 = XmlService.createElement('canvas');
var context = canvas1.getContext('2d');
```

Error:

> TypeError: canvas1.getContext is not a function (line 8, file "Code")

I am not sure how to fix or get around this.

Comment: It is possible to create byte array from image blobs. That's about it. To convert image to pixels, You would need a image parser.  Something like [this](https://github.com/foliojs/png.js) => browserify and eval it in apps script. Expect plenty of errors and potential complete failure

Comment: The thing is, could I implement this into Google Apps Script?

Comment: I'm just giving you a general overview of  how the process to implement it in apps script would look like. Apps script doesn't support "import"/"export"=> browserify would remove all such dependencies. Whether you'll run into any other  problem, I don't know. All canvas: "Image()" and "ImageData()" doesn't seem to be supported. If the parser uses any of that it'll fail. Another way is to create a feature request for [ImageData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageData/ImageData) on [IssueTracker](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "canvas element" your are asking for is part of [Canvas API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API).

Google Apps Script doesn't include functions for the canvas element, actually it doesn't include any function for any Web APIs elements.

The XMLService Service has the [Class Element](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml-service/element), this is

> A representation of an XML Element node.

Comment: If I create an XML canvas Class thing, can I use it's methods to get pixel colors as I want?

Comment: What do you mean by "XML canvas Class thing"? Are you already familiar with the Google Apps Script runtimes? If so, which one will you use?

Comment: I'm actually not very familiar with them, because I just started working with Google Apps Script a few days ago. Could I use a representation of an XML node to get individual pixel colors?

Comment: Please post a new question.

Answer (score 1):

You created an element with: `var canvas1 = XmlService.createElement('canvas');`

[These are the methods for an element](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml-service/element)

Comment: Thanks for the response! So exactly how would I go about creating a blank canvas element, that I only want to use for it's methods? My goal is to .drawImage onto the blank canvas, and then call getImageData on it.

Comment: I would do it in an html file rather that google apps script file.

Comment: I'm trying to create a simple API using google apps script. The whole point was to get pixels of an image using Google Apps Script, and I don't know any other method than to use a canvas. What would you recommend I do?